# What is "System management in its operational setting" requirement?

Tags: analysis

I was reading [Applying UML and Patterns](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=r8i-4En_aa4C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=System%20management%20in%20its%20operational%20setting&source=bl&ots=mX2CQYupN4&sig=V-Gk0rSY50WHhOLhLoj5UK0TFm0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=System%20management%20in%20its%20operational%20setting&f=false).

In the FURPS+ section, I read this one for +:
Operations - system management in its operational setting.

I just can't understand this sentence and I can't map it to a non-functional requirement.
I would be appreciated if anyone could help me with it.

and another question:
as far as I know, the + part of FURPS+ is different in other sources. so what's the point of it? I think it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I read more, the book gives an example:

operational concerns (for example, how do errors get handled, or how often
to do backups?)

but the second question still remains...